# Role-based Security with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a web login application using forms authentication and role authentication.

I'm not so familiar with the role authentication , I've searched in google for some tutorials but I couldn't understand.

So ,

1.For creating an user with a certain role everything must be done here:
http://i1.asp.net/asp.net/images/pss/module08_06.jpg ( but , I want to store users info and roles in the asp.net sql database )

What I thought so far is to create a database with the followings table columns:

```
1.ID(int,primary)
2.Username(varchar(10))
3.Password(varchar(10))
4.RoleType(varchar(10)) - Roles are : Admin / User
```

On login , check if the user&pass are valid if yes then select the roletype from the database for the current user .

```
If roletype = Admin 
   Redirect to a certain page
else if roletype = user
   Redirect to other page
```

But I don't think asp.net web page knows that the column RoleType is used for roles and it doesn't make sense , I mean there's no conection between   and my column for called RoleType

```
<location path="\Admin\">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="Admin"/> //this 
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
```

So , if anyone wouldn't mind helping me , I would really appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign roles to user in global.asax, you can refer below tutorial
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Assign-Roles-to-Users-in-ASPNet-Form-Based-Authentication.aspx

Comment: thank you arun for your comment.Actually i have read that article. But I can't understand the syntax mentioned in that article. I'm Really new to this asp.net development. If You can please suggest me a different article or video serious which helps to understand this forms authentication better. Thanks in Advanced...!!!